# How to get Price value from <p> tag on click in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I am not able to get value of `<p>` or price of product in javascript Below is my code.i want to get `Mobile.Price` in js

```javascript
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Product Catalog" >
        <lightning-combobox style="width: 20%;"
            title="Select Category"
            options={showCategory}
            onchange={getCategory}
            value={value}>
        </lightning-combobox>
    </lightning-card>
    <template if:true={showProduct}>
        <div class="content">
            <template  for:each={Mobile}  for:item="Mobile" >
                <div draggable={draggable} ondragstart={handleDragStart} key={Name} >
                    <a onclick={handleClick} value={Mobile.Price}>
        
                        <img
                            src={Mobile.image}
                            class="product slds-align_absolute-center"
                            alt="Product picture"
                        />
                        <div>
                            <p class="title slds-align_absolute-center">{Mobile.Name}</p>
                            <p data-id="price" class="form-control slds-align_absolute-center" >
                                MSRP:&nbsp;{Mobile.Price}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Product Catalog" >
        <lightning-combobox style="width: 20%;"
            title="Select Category"
            options={showCategory}
            onchange={getCategory}
            value={value}>
        </lightning-combobox>
    </lightning-card>
    <template if:true={showProduct}>
        <div class="content">
            <template  for:each={Mobile}  for:item="Mobile" >
            <div draggable={draggable} ondragstart={handleDragStart} key={Name} >
                <a onclick={handleClick} value={Mobile.Price}>
                    <img
                        src={Mobile.image}
                        class="product slds-align_absolute-center"
                        alt="Product picture"
                    />
                    <div>
                        <p class="title slds-align_absolute-center">{Mobile.Name}</p>
                        <p data-id="price" class="form-control slds-align_absolute-center" >
                            MSRP:&nbsp;***{Mobile.Price}***
                       </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
</template>
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import Ultra22 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Ultra22';
import Iphone13 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Iphone13';
export default class ProductCatalog extends LightningElement {
    showCategory = [
        {label:'Mobile Phones',value:'Mobile'},
        {label:'Toys',value:'Toys'}
    ];
    total = 0;
    Mobile =[ {
            "Name":"samsung 22 Ultra",
            "Price":"$1800",
            "image":Ultra22
        },
        {
            "Name":"Iphone 13 Pro",
            "Price":"$1850",
            "image":Iphone13
        }
    ]
    getProduct;
    showProduct = false;
    getCategory(event) {
        this.showProduct = true;
        this.getProduct = event.detail.value;
        console.log('get Category>>>'+this.getProduct)
    }
    handleClick(event) {
        const editor  = this.template.querySelector('**????**');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of `Event.currentTarget` from the event given to the click handler.

I console.log out the value but I also get the selected row of data first. Typically there will be something else from the row you'll need.

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Product Catalog">
        <lightning-combobox style="width: 20%;" title="Select Category" options={showCategory} onchange={getCategory}
            value={value}> </lightning-combobox>
    </lightning-card>
    <template if:true={showProduct}>
        <div class="content">
            <template for:each={Mobile} for:item="Mobile">
                <div draggable={draggable} ondragstart={handleDragStart} key={Mobile.key} onclick={handleClick} data-name={Mobile.Name}>
                    <a>

                        <div>
                            <img
                src={Mobile.image}
                class="product slds-align_absolute-center"
                alt="Product picture"
            />
                            <p class="title slds-align_absolute-center">{Mobile.Name}</p>
                            <p data-id="price" class="form-control slds-align_absolute-center">
                                MSRP:&nbsp;{Mobile.Price}

                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </a>
                </div>

            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import Ultra22 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Ultra22';
import Iphone13 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Iphone13';
export default class ProductCatalog extends LightningElement {
    showCategory = [
        { label: 'Mobile Phones', value: 'Mobile' },
        { label: 'Toys', value: 'Toys' }
    ];
    total = 0;
    Mobile = [{
        "Name": "samsung 22 Ultra",
        "Price": "$1800",
        "image": Ultra22
    },
    {
        "Name": "Iphone 13 Pro",
        "Price": "$1850",
        "image": Iphone13
    }]
    .map((mobile,i) => ({
        key: `_key${i}`,
        ...mobile,
    }))

    getProduct;
    showProduct = false;

    getCategory(event) {
        this.showProduct = true;
        this.getProduct = event.detail.value;
        console.log('get Category>>>' + this.getProduct)
    }

    handleClick(event) {

        const { name } = event.currentTarget?.dataset;
        console.log(`Clicked row is ${name}`);
        const selected = this.Mobile.find(m => m.Name === name);
        console.log(selected);
        console.log(selected.value);
    }
}
```

There were errors from invalid keys so i added a map to add unique keys the objects in the Mobile array.

Hope it helps

Comment: its giving output as  Clicked row is undefined
 undefined

Comment: i am looking to fetch (Mobile.Price} value fromt that <p> tag

Answer (score 0):

When an lwc component loads, it's id attribute will dynamically change and tracking the component becomes difficult using id value. So we can use native html **data-*** attribute to resolve this. Since your `<p>` tag contains **data-id** attribute (Which is a category of data-*) , you can use below code snipped to query the element in javascript.

```
 let mobilePrice = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="price"]');
 console.log("Mobile price in javascript ===>"+mobilePrice);
```

You can refer this [blog](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-element-by-data-attribute#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20querySelector%20method%20to,the%20examples%20in%20this%20article.) for more information.

Comment: I am getting this output in console    ===>SecureElement: [object HTMLParagraphElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }

Comment: i am looking to fetch (Mobile.Price} value fromt that <p> tag